# Subtract Result of Two Queries in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I am having difficulty with the syntax of my final query. I have two queries and I want the final query to subtract the two of them and display the result of that subtraction. Here's what I have:

```
SELECT
       PlaneType.Capacity
FROM (
       PlaneType
INNER JOIN Aircraft
       ON PlaneType.TypeCode = Aircraft.TypeCode
       )
INNER JOIN ScheduledFlight
       ON Aircraft.SerialNum = ScheduledFlight.SerialNum 
WHERE
       ScheduledFlight.FlightNum = [Enter Flight Number]
AND
       ScheduledFlight.FlightDate = [Enter Flight Date];
```

That query displays the capacity of my airplane. Then I have this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(PassID)
FROM (
       Reservation
INNER JOIN ScheduledFlight
       ON Reservation.FlightNum = ScheduledFlight.FlightNum
       )
WHERE
       ScheduledFlight.FlightNum = [Enter Flight Number]
AND
       Reservation.FlightDate = [Enter Flight Date];
```

That query displays the number of reservations for the flight of a specific plane. Let's say the capacity of the plane is 300 and I have 2 reservations, I want my query to display 298. Any help is appreciated.

Best,

Comment: Your question and work so far hints at the use of 'set operators', namely the `minus` operator.  A quick bit of searching suggests minus is not supported by Access.  The good news is you don't need set operators for this data structure.  This comment is just a general hint about a way forward.  That is, I think you should be able to create a single query that beings with `SELECT PlaneType.Capacity, COUNT(PassId)`

Comment: Well, that crashed Access, haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pulls together all of your tables to find the result:

```
SELECT PlaneType.Capacity - Count(Reservation.[PassID]) AS AvailableSeats
FROM (
    (
    Aircraft INNER JOIN PlaneType ON Aircraft.TypeCode = PlaneType.TypeCode
    ) INNER JOIN ScheduledFlight ON Aircraft.[SerialNum] = ScheduledFlight.[SerialNum]
    )
INNER JOIN Reservation ON (ScheduledFlight.FlightNum = Reservation.FlightNum)
    AND (ScheduledFlight.FlightDate = Reservation.FlightDate)
GROUP BY Reservation.FlightNum,
    Reservation.FlightDate,
    PlaneType.Capacity
HAVING (
    ((Reservation.FlightNum) = [Enter Flight Number])
    AND ((Reservation.FlightDate) = [Enter Flight Date])
    );
```

Comment: Well, when running my query there should be two questions asked: Flight number and date. This is asking for passenger ID, flight number, flight date, and serial number of the aircraft. I do see it creates a column caled Count of Passengers but ultimately I just need one column as the output with the total number of seats available: Capacity - Reservations based on a flight and a date.

Comment: I've corrected the field names now. It should only prompt you for the Flight Number and the Date now. Also it is only returning the capacity minus the reservations. I hope this will work for you.